# Android Application Architecture

Tags: android, user-interface, sudoku

I am currently designing a Sudoku application for my own personal development, this is the first proper application I will be making. I can program in Java quite effectively with good object orientated understanding.

I want to create the application with 1 view as shown below:
[image]

As you can see I would like a single view with a grid object, the grid object will have it's own paint method.

How would I go about making this object zoomable? 
How would I handle interaction with this object?

I also have 2 buttons on the bottom left and right,
How would I anchor these so they won't zoom?
Could I float these over the object and have the object as the entire view?

What pop up menu should I use? I would like a small menu with difficulty selection a restart button or a new puzzle button, also an exit button.

Thanks for reading this far, if you do have any advice for me at all then please post, If you require more information about anything then please ask!

Comment: Did you considered to create class inherited from standard GridView http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html ? You can use default listeners for click, long clicks, etc. and custom FrameLayout to make it zoomable.

Comment: This is definitely something I will look into thank-you for the information :) this will make the grid object I create much easier to make

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this Android Developers tutorial useful in achieving your zooming aims - https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html. It refers to an ImageView but with some changes I believe it could work similarly with your subclass of GridView.

You wouldn't have to worry about the buttons as long as the zoom was applied only to the GridView. However, you may wish to consider using an [Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) instead of your current buttons for the menu and hint button.